# GridView Export to Pdf Error

Tags: asp.net, itext

I get Error While Converting Gridview to Pdf With ITextSharp dll ..The Gridview Also Contains Some Images of Products.

```
try
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
    "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Gridbill.AllowPaging = false;

    Gridbill.AllowSorting = false;

    Gridbill.DataBind();

    Gridbill.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/bills/" + random.ToString() + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create));
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    clientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + e.Message + "');", true);
}
```

Here random is a randomly generated number from ( 1000 to int max).
I am getting error at htmlParse.parse line . Can Any1 Help me Please and Suggest me some modifications to make it working ..

Comment: Can you tell us the error? Also, unrelated to your problem, remove the line `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` because it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Error States that --  network path was not found..

Comment: And which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: htmparser.Parse(sr) line gives error ...The network path was not found

Comment: Inspect your string, look for any paths that are not absolute and fully qualified. Remember, iTextSharp does not know anything about your application especially where it "lives". You are not feeding it a URL to determine relative links, you are feeding it raw naked HTML that has no context.

Comment: Thanks .So i have to just replace image url's With absolute urls? Right??

Comment: That should fix things. Obviously the images need to exist and the local unauthenticated `WebClient` (which is what iText uses) needs to be able to access them, too.